# Controls gets moved below bottom in Chrome on Mobile

Tags: css

My friend and I are currenlty trying to create a form with various steps.

When on a small enough screen, controls are being show at the bottom of the screen to indicate the user can go to the next step.

Unfortunately, on Chrome these controls are being somewhat hidden because the top bar is offsettings the entire view, like so: [image]

What is the best approach to ensure that the controls are being shown fully when the user visits the page without them having to actually scroll down?

Comment: "within them having to actually scroll down"? So you want the user to scroll down to see the controls or do you want to show the controls without the need to scroll down?

Comment: @Aaron3219 Typo sorry. The latter, the user shoulnd't have to scroll down in order for the to see the controls. I've updated the post :)

Comment: Alright one last question and I will know what you want: Should the controls always be visible even if the user has to scroll down for some reason (e.g. the page is very long because of much content)?

Comment: @Aaron3219 Exactly, they should always be visible to the user in those cases :)

Comment: I believe with a simple margin-bottom you can fix it. try using media queries for small resolutions. if you couldn't solve this, share you code here to see what you've done.

Comment: I will make it to an answer if you confirm it but it seems too simple: Have you tried `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`? Because on my android in works fine and stays on the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it seemed too simple but after clarification in the comments the answer is to use `position:fixed; bottom:0;`. Documentation about `position: fixed` can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp):

> An element with `position: fixed` is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.